# Editing adb backup files

Tags: adb, backup

I want to edit the contents of an `.adb` backup file. I found a command to extract the contents:

`dd if=mybackup.adb bs=24 skip=1 | zlib-flate -uncompress | tar xf -`

I edited the extracted files as needed but how do I build adb files with the modified files?

I thought of streaming the directory, compressing it with zlib-flate and generating the tar file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the preferred way for extracting such backup archives is [Android Backup Extractor (abe)](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) (requires installed Java Runtime).

It allows to convert adb backup archives to tar files and also the reverse way to convert TAR files back to an adb backup files that can be restored via adb:

```
java -jar abe.jar unpack mybackup.ab mybackup.tar
```

Modify created file `mybackup.tar`.

```
java -jar abe.jar pack mybackup.tar mybackup_mod.ab
adb restore mybackup_mod.ab
```

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1572600&page=2

Comment: actually, it still works on my huawei p smart.